# Where is the module LinearRegression in the directory sklearn/linear_model/?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I want to see the source code of LinearRegression but there is no such file as LinearRegression.py in the folder linear_model.

When I write a program with:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

It works, so I assume LinearRegression is included in my library.

I am using anaconda3 with python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to see the source code of `LinearRegression` but not directly from the command line as you are trying to do.

`LinearRegression` is a class and its code is located in `base.py` (see below the link for this).

The source code of a function(in general) can be found in the `sklearn` documentation website/github.

For the `LinearRegression` the documentation is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html.

The source code is here starting from line 405: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L405.

Finally, you may also find the source code in: `scikit-learn/sklearn/linear_model/base.py`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful indeed

Comment: @SounakBiswas glad that I could help. If the answer was clear you could accept it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sera excellent answer, I think it should be noted that IDEs often have a feature to jump directly to the source code of arbitrary definitions.

For example, in Sypder right-click on the name and select *Go to definition*:
[image]

In PyCharm right click and select *Go To* -> *Declaration*:
[image]

In the particular example, both IDEs will open `base.py` where `LinearRegression` is defined.

Comment: Thank you for such a generalised answer. In pycharm it actually highlights the __init__ function of the class.

Comment: @SounakBiswas You are welcome. Yep, PyCharm jumps to the `__init__` function. I think this is fine because it is *usually* defined as the first function in the class.